# image editor module

Tags: media

I've installed the [Image Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageeditor) module. and config the stetting. but when I add a node and upload image, then I edit image using the links but couldn't save image and replace with original image and show this message:

> Warning: filesize(): stat failed for temporary://Tulips_12.jpg in filefield_sources_save_file() (line 451 of /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/farhangi/public/dev/sites/all/modules/filefield_sources/filefield_sources.module).
>   the temporary://Tulips_12.jpg could'nt copy because there are no exist file with this name.please check the name of file is correct or no.
>   please helpe me 
>   thanks

Comment: Check your /tmp directory here `/admin/config/media/file-system` and make sure it has proper permissions set